# Scala stream computation throws StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, stream, stack-overflow

Why this code snippet execution results in `StackOverflowError`:

```
lazy val primes: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3, 2) filter { pc =>
  primes.takeWhile(x => x * x <= pc) forall (p => pc % p != 0)
}
primes.take(5).last
```

while this code snippet works just fine (see the dot before `filter`):

```
lazy val primes: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3, 2).filter { pc =>
  primes.takeWhile(x => x * x <= pc) forall (p => pc % p != 0)
}
primes.take(5).last
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses will make the order of execution more apparent here. The following two definitions of `primes` are equivalent to their respective counterparts in the OP.

```
// fails with stack overflow
lazy val primes: Stream[Int] = (2 #:: Stream.from(3, 2)) filter { pc =>
  primes.takeWhile(x => x * x <= pc) forall (p => pc % p != 0)
}

// succeeds
lazy val primes: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: (Stream.from(3, 2).filter { pc =>
  primes.takeWhile(x => x * x <= pc) forall (p => pc % p != 0)
})
```

Okay, so what's wrong with the first one? It is defined first by creating the stream `(2 #:: Stream.from(3, 2))`, then filtering it. Let's try to access the first element:

```
primes.head
```

This actually also produces a stack overflow. Here's what happens:

1. `head` attempts to access the first element of `primes`.
2. The first element `2` must be checked against the `filter` predicate.
3. To check the predicate, we must recursively access `primes`.
4. We attempt to take the first element of `primes`, which must run the `filter` predicate on `2`.
5. Repeat step 3.

...Which leads to the stack overflow.

The second example does not suffer from this problem, because the head of the `Stream` (`2`) isn't filtered, so there is no recursive at that step to check if `2` is really there or not. In other words, in the second example, it is clear that `2` is the `head` of the `Stream`. In the first example, the `head` of the `Stream` must be computed by checking the `filter`, but in order to do so refers to itself in an infinite recursive loop.